# Sending custom commands to a TUN/TAP Interface

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I am implementing a user-space network device that makes use of the Linux [TUN/TAP driver](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt). Is it possible to install a custom ioctl handler? I would like to be able to send custom status queries and control commands to the program. Or perhaps there is a slicker way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the program listen on another normal socket (AF_LOCAL, AF_INET6, ... non-tun in any case) of your choice.

Comment: That seems to be the best way to go